# How do I use Entity Framework Extensions BulkInsert and AllowDuplicateKeys

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am importing data from a CSV file into a SQL Server DB, the CSV may contain duplicate entries.
My existing code uses SqlBulkCopy() and "IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON", all is well with duplicates.

I am switching to code first using EF Core with Zzz Projects Entity Framework Extensions.

Primary keys are defined in DbContext:

```cs
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            if (modelBuilder == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));

            modelBuilder.Entity<AmbientWeatherData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApcUpsData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
            modelBuilder.Entity<PurpleAirData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Vr1710Data>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Vr1710EventData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp, u.Type });
            modelBuilder.Entity<WeatherGooseData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
            modelBuilder.Entity<WundergroundData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
            modelBuilder.Entity<WundergroundDailyData>()
                .HasKey(u => new { u.TimeStamp });
        }
```

Data is inserted using BulkInsert:

```cs
dbContext.BulkInsert(data, options => options.AllowDuplicateKeys = true);
```

Exception when inserting duplicates:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Vr1710Data'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Vr1710Data'. The duplicate key value is (2014 - 12 - 28 14:26:07.0000000).

The function that inserts the data is generic and type agnostic.

```cs
        public static bool Import<TDataType, TLoaderType, TConfigType>(string fileName, string connectionString)
            where TLoaderType : TelemetryLoader<TDataType, TConfigType>, new()
            where TConfigType : TelemetryConfig
            where TDataType : TelemetryData
        {
// ...
}
```

The online examples for `BulkInsert()` and `AllowDuplicateKeys` require the use of `ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression`
From: https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert#insert-only-if-the-entity-not-already-exists

```
context.BulkInsert(customers, options => {
    options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
    options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = c => c.Code;
});
```

How can I ignore duplicates without needing a specialization for `ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression` for every data type, but instead use my keys as defined in the DbContext?

Comment: the best case would be to write a program to remove duplicates before inserting into db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I ignore duplicates without needing a specialization for ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression for every data type, but instead use my keys as defined in the DbContext?

By default, the library already takes the key from the `DbContext`.

In the example, `c.Code` was representing a custom key (The `CustomerID` is the real key).

If I understand correctly the problem, you need to use the following code:

```
context.BulkInsert(customers, options => {
    options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
    options.AllowDuplicateKeys = true;
});
```

Both options are required.